# Select cursor query

Tags: sql, oracle, select, cursor

I was expecting results for this query

```
select cursor (select *
                 from Dba_Source
                where Owner = 'ORD'
                  and Upper(Text) Like ob)
  from (select '''%' || object_name || '%''' ob
          from dba_objects
         where owner = 'ORD'
           and object_name = 'ORD_USERS');
```

Since one of the stored procedure in `ORD` schema has used the table `ORD_USERS`.

Can someone please let me know what's wrong?

When I run these queries separately they are returning results like

```
select '''%' || object_name || '%''' ob
  from dba_objects
 where owner = 'ORD' and object_name = 'ORD_USERS';

'%ORD_USERS%'

select *
  from Dba_Source
 where Owner = 'ORD'
   and Upper(Text) like '%ORD_USERS%';

Owner Name     Type          Line  Text
----- -------- ------------- ----- ---------------
ORD   ORD_PKG  PACKAGE_BODY  126   FROM ORD_USERS,
```

Comment: What results do you expect your query to return?  What results are you actually getting?  I would guess that you really just want `select * from dba_source where upper(text) like '%ORD_USERS%'`.

Comment: Try moving the ''%' and '%'' wild cards from the inner query to the outer one.  It could be a case where the optimizer handles the strings as face value rather than as wild card strings.

Comment: 1) I am just doing it for one table in the above query, so what you said was right, but my final goal is to check for all tables in a schema.                              2) if I moved it to the outer query the OB is being taken literally and searching for OB instead of the table name that resulted form the inner query

Comment: I meant like ''%' || ob || '%'' in the outer.  So it doesn't lose the functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully the following example will demonstrate both the issue and the solution for you:

```
with sample_data as (select 'fredbobgeorge' str from dual union all
                     select '''fredbobgeorge''' str from dual)
select 'with quoted like' search_type,
       str
from   sample_data
where  str like (select '''%bob%''' from dual)
union all
select 'without quoted like' search_type,
       str
from   sample_data
where  str like (select '%bob%' from dual);

SEARCH_TYPE         STR            
------------------- ---------------
with quoted like    'fredbobgeorge'
without quoted like fredbobgeorge  
without quoted like 'fredbobgeorge'
```

Comment: Thanks Boneist, its working once I removed the quotes from the sub query. but why is that , I was trying to provide what exact the main quey would look for '%SERACH_STRING%' , but why is it still expecting %SEARCH_STRING%

Comment: single quotes are what you use to tell Oracle that the text between the two is actually a string literal. When you select something that is a string and use it in another query, Oracle already knows it's a string, so you don't need to put single quotes around it

Comment: Thanks for letting me know